# Perl decimal to ASCII conversion

Tags: regex, perl, ascii, decimal

I am pulling SNMP information from an F5 LTM, and storing this information in a psql database. I need help converting the returned data in decimal format into ASCII characters.
Here is an example of the information returned from the SNMP request:

```
iso.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.2.10.2.3.1.9.10.102.111.114.119.97.114.100.95.118.115 = Counter64: 0
```

In my script, I need to identify the different sections of this information:

```
my ($prefix, $num, $char-len, $vs) = ($oid =~ /($vsTable)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(.+)/);
```

This gives me the following:

```
(prefix= .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.2.10.2.3.1)  
(num= 9 ) 
(char-len= 10 ) 
(vs= 102.111.114.119.97.114.100.95.118.115)
```

The variable `$vs` is the Object name in decimal format. I would like to convert this to ASCII characters (which should be "forward_vs").
Does anyone have a suggestion on how to do this?

Comment: What have you tried? What function don't you understand -- `split`, `chr`, `sprintf`, or `pack`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my $new_vs = join("", map { chr($_) } split(/\./,$vs));
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to suggest a solution. This worked very well!

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is related to interpreting SNMP data, it seems logical to me to use one or more of the [SNMP modules](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=snmp&mode=all) available from CPAN.  You have to know quite a lot about SNMP to determine when the string you quote stops being the identifier (prefix) and starts to be the value.  You have a better chance of getting a general solution with SNMP code than with hand-hacked code.

Answer (score 1):

Jonathan Leffler has the right answer, but here are a couple of things to expand your Perl horizons:

```
use v5.10;
$_ = "102.111.114.119.97.114.100.95.118.115";
say "Version 1: " => eval;
say "Version 2: " => pack "W".(1+y/.//) => /\d+/g;
```

Executed, that prints:

```
Version 1: forward_vs
Version 2: forward_vs
```

Once both are clear to you, you may hit space to continue or q to quit. :)

EDIT: The last one can also be written

```
pack "WW".y/.//,/\d+/g
```

But please don't. :)

Comment: I suspect these are bytes, not unicode code points, so "C" would be more appropriate.

Comment: Version 1 fails for `""`, `"102"` and `"102.111"`.

Comment: `"W".(1+y/.//)` can be replaced with `"W*"` (or better yet, `"C*"`).

Comment: I started with `"A*"`. Not sure why I didn't use `"C*"`. The `W` is so I don't have to think about signed chars. :)

Comment: @tchrist Can you explain why the eval decodes the numbers into ascii?

Comment: @TLP: It doesn't.  It decodes them into Unicode.  Just as `printf "%vd", "cats and dogs"` produces `99.97.116.115.32.97.110.100.32.100.111.103.115`, so too will `print 99.97.116.115.32.97.110.100.32.100.111.103.115` produce `"cats and dogs"`.  It's a v-string, where you have a vector of code points.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
$ascii .= chr for split /\./, $vs;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pack 'C*', split /\./
```

For example,

```
>perl -E"say pack 'C*', split /\./, $ARGV[0]" 102.111.114.119.97.114.100.95.118.115
forward_vs
```

Comment: Actually, a minor detail, but it would rather be `perl -E 'say pack "C*", split /\./, $ARGV[0]' 102.111.114.119.97.114.100.95.118.115`, because otherwise your shell would interpolate your `$ARGV` resulting into nothing.

Comment: @Jacques It didn't result in nothing, so that should have been your first clue what you said was wrong. In fact, the command not only works, but your command doesn't. It produces `Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.`. And that's because the Windows command shell was used as indicated by the `>` prompt.

Comment: I see, thank you @ikegami. I should have pointed out that it does not work on a Unix terminal then and mine does work on a Unix terminal. The windows prompt was not obvious to me. I am not familiar with it.

Comment: @Jacques, No, you should not have mentioned anything at all. It's not relevant to the question or the answer: Use `pack 'C*', split /\./`
`